# This script make the ftp account but what ever is the php file define?

Tags: api, ftp, cpanel, account

Please help me out anyone I beg you I have been searching for a month every day trying different things nothing is working.

This below script will make the ftp account but what it define in the line as "add ftp account" as test directory , How can I connect this script to html form so this script can work through that html form to create a ftp account. thank You

```
   <?php
$conn = array ( 'host' => 'Domain Name'
              , 'port' => '2083'
              , 'user' => 'Not Avi'
              , 'pass' => 'Not Avi'
              ) ;

function cpanel_api ( $conn , $type , $user , $pass , $domain )
{
 if ( $conn [ 'port' ] == '2087' || $conn [ 'port' ] == '2083' || $conn [ 'port' ] == '443' )
 {
    $site = 'https://' . $conn [ 'host' ] . ':' . $conn [ 'port' ] ;
 } else {
    $site = 'http://' . $conn [ 'host' ] . ':' . $conn [ 'port' ] ;
 }

 switch ( $type )
 {
    case 'add_ftp' :
     $xmlin = '<cpanelaction><module>Ftp</module><func>addftp</func><apiversion>1</apiversion><args>' . $user . '</args><args>' . $pass . '</args><args>/' . $user . '</args><args>20</args></cpanelaction>' ;
     break ;

    case 'del_ftp' :
     $xmlin = '<cpanelaction><module>Ftp</module><func>delftp</func><apiversion>1</apiversion><args>' . $user . '</args><args>1</args></cpanelaction>' ;
     break ;

    case 'add_subdomain' :
     $xmlin = '<cpanelaction><module>SubDomain</module><func>addsubdomain</func><apiversion>1</apiversion><args>' . $user . '</args><args>' . $domain . '</args><args>0</args><args>0</args><args>/' . $user . '</args></cpanelaction>' ;
     break ;

    case 'del_subdomain' :
     $xmlin = '<cpanelaction><module>SubDomain</module><func>delsubdomain</func><apiversion>2</apiversion><args><domain>' . $user . $domain . '</domain></args></cpanelaction>' ;
     break ;

    default :
     echo 'Type error' ;
 }

 if ( $type == 'add_ftp' || $type == 'del_ftp' || $type == 'add_subdomain' || $type == 'del_subdomain' )
 {
  $query = '/xml-api/cpanel?user=' . $conn [ 'user' ] . '&xmlin=' . $xmlin ;

  $curl = curl_init ( ) ;
  curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER , 0 ) ;
  curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER , 1 ) ;
  curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST , 0 ) ;
  curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_USERPWD        , $conn [ 'user' ] . ':' . $conn [ 'pass' ] ) ;
  curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_HEADER         , 0 ) ;
  curl_setopt ( $curl, CURLOPT_URL            , $site . $query ) ;
  $result = curl_exec ( $curl ) ;
  curl_close ( $curl ) ;
 }
}

/***** ADD Subdomain and FTP Account *****/
cpanel_api ( $conn , 'add_subdomain' , 'test' , '0123456789' , '.domain.com' ) ;
cpanel_api ( $conn , 'add_ftp'       , 'test' , '0123456789' , '.domain.com' ) ;

/***** DEL Subdomain and FTP Account *****/
//cpanel_api ( $conn , 'del_subdomain' , 'test' , '0123456789' , '.domain.com' ) ;
//cpanel_api ( $conn , 'del_ftp'       , 'test' , '0123456789' , '.domain.com' ) ;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

how to create ftp account in cpanel :

```
<?
$user = $cpenal_user; // the cpenal root username
$pass = $cpenal_pass; // the cpanel root password
$domain = $site_domain; // the cpanel root domain
$fquota = $drive_space; // ftp disc space mb (for new ftp account)
$skin = 'x3'; // cpnel version


$fuser =  //the username for the new  FTP account
$fpass =  //default password for new ftp account

$uri = '/directiry/'; // the internal URL to the FTP home folder /directiry/ 


if (mkdir($uri, 0777)) { //make the tmp directory
    $fDirectory = '/directiry/';

    //$fuser = $feedUser;

    $fhomedir = '/public_html/' . $fDirectory;


    $url = "https://$user:$pass@$domain:2083/frontend/$skin/ftp/doaddftp.html?";
    $url = $url . "login=$fuser&password=$fpass&homedir=$fhomedir&quota=$fquota";

    $result = @file_get_contents($url);
    if (preg_match('/(Account created successfully)/', $result)) {

       //ftp created with new directory
    }} ?>
```

Comment: If this is running in an environment where people don't have full access to the ftp server anyway; using $fuser, or $fpass in this way may be unsafe if someone enters a password such as 

"s33kre7&homedir=/&quota=999999#" 

In general: always sanatize user input.